# Joomla: post redirects to profile page or give 404 error

Tags: redirect, authentication, profile, joomla1.6

I know Joomla 1.6 is old, the site isn't mine.

The problem: after logging in as normal site user using a menu link, a redirect to a special info page should be performed. But, the post itself (apparently) redirects to the user's profile page, which is not desired.
When I try to call the post directly it's the same. If not logged in, 404 not found error pops up.

Any ideas?

Edit: the 404 says "Category not found". The post has the category "Uncategorised", like most of the other posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess no one's interested in the answer, but I'll post it anyway.
The problem was the caching system (it used to work for like 15 min and break after that time). I deactivated it and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Using Joomla 3.8.10, and I recently hand the same problem.  Log into Joomla, member sees 404 page. Clearing the Joomla cache solved the problem (at least for now).  Thank you so much to Robert K. for posting his solution.

---

Update #1 -- Shree, good info.  My primary purpose was to show that the solution of clearing the cache would still work for Joomla 3.8.10, which is many years newer that Joomla 1.6. Almost no one uses Joomla 1.6 anymore.

---

Update #2 - Clearing the Joomla cache was only a temporary solution, because the problem came back again. I had to disable the new Joomla extension of CJBlog, which I had just installed. And, then clearing Joomla cache cured my login-shows-404 problem.

Comment: *Robin, not Robert :)
Anway thanks for the insight, I will check this on my sites.